# Using emphasis pronouns

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Is the following sentence correct?

> I myself, am interested (in something/to know/hear/learn etc. (that)).

or

> I am interested (in something/to know/hear/learn etc. (that)) myself.

Comment: "am interested", not "am interest"

Comment: No, i just meant both of them need to say "interested". I did not say whether either one would be correct after you fix "interest". Also I don't know what you mean by "true".

Comment: I, myself, am interested **in** helping you. But "helping you" is not a sentence. I am also interested **to** know which example you think is correct, and why.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock i think the first example is true! because  `myself` must came after the pronoun if it should be an emphasis pronoun!

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Also i think `interested in` is correct! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the sentences are not only grammatically incorrect but also don't make much sense.

First, you cannot say "I am not interest". You should use here the adjective "interested".  You can use this adjective in the following patterns:

1. Adj + in + somebody/something such as I am interested in her/this job.
2. Adj + to infinitive + somebody/something such I am interested to help him/to do this job.
3. Adj + in + -ing form + somebody/something such as I am interested in helping him/in doing this job.

As for the emphatic pronouns you can use it as follows:

I myself am interested in this job, or doing this job, or to do this job.

I am interested in this job myself, or in doing this job myself, or to do this job myself.